# How to get values of dynamic id in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

As i'm new to javascript i'm struggling to to get input values of dynamically generated id.

```js
        var i = 0;

    function addRow() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');    

     div.className = 'rTableRow';
        div.id = 'Taxrow' + i;
     

        div.innerHTML =
              '<div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="product'+i+'" id="product'+i+'" placeholder="Product Name"></div>\
           <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="price'+i+'"  id="price'+i+'" placeholder="Item Price"></div>\
           <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="qty'+i+'" id="qty'+i+'" onchange="subTotal();" placeholder="Item Quantity"></div>\
        <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" id="tax'+i+'" onkeyup="Total();" placeholder="Tax Percentage"></div>\
        <div class="rTableCell"><input name="subtotal'+i+'" type="text" id="subtotal'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
        <div class="rTableCell"><input name="salestax'+i+'" type="text" id="salestax'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
        <div class="rTableCell"><input name="gtotal'+i+'" type="text" id="gtotal'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
               <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(this)">';

        document.getElementById('dyncalc').appendChild(div);

     i=i+1;
    }


    function removeRow(input) {
        document.getElementById('dyncalc').removeChild(input.parentNode);
    }
    /*
    function setValue(node){
        var price = document.getElementById(node.value).value;
        //alert(price);
    }​

    */

    function subTotal() {
     
    /*  var price = document.getElementById('price[i]').value;
      var qty = document.getElementById('qty[i]').value;*/

      var price = document.TaxCalculator.price.value;
      var qty = document.TaxCalculator.qty.value;

      var productPrice = price * qty;

      document.TaxCalculator.subtotal.value = productPrice.toFixed(2);
      return productPrice;
    }

    function Total() {
      var subtotal = subTotal();
      var stax = (document.TaxCalculator.tax.value) / 100 ;

        tax = subtotal * stax ;

      document.TaxCalculator.subtotal.value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
      document.TaxCalculator.salestax.value = tax.toFixed(2);

      var gtotal = subtotal + tax;

      document.TaxCalculator.gtotal.value = gtotal.toFixed(2);
    }
```

```css
     .taxCalculator h3{
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #ffffff;
     }
     .rTable { display: table; }
     .rTableRow { display: table-row; }
     .rTableHeading { display: table-header-group; }
     .rTableBody { display: table-row-group; }
     .rTableFoot { display: table-footer-group; }
     .rTableCell, .rTableHead { display: table-cell; }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Dynamic Tax Calculator</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="taxCalculator">
     <div class="container">
     <p></p>
     <div class="card">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;" class="card-header bg-info">Tax Caluculator </h3>
       <p></p>
      <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
      <form action="" name="TaxCalculator" id="TaxCalculator" class="form-inline">
      <div class="rTable" id="dyncalc">
       <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="AddItems" onclick="addRow()"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><label for="product" >Product Name</label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="price" >Price</label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="qty" >Item Qty</label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="tax" >Tax Percentage (%) </label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="subtotal" >Sub Total: </label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="salestax" >Tax :</label></div>
           <div class="rTableHead"><label for="gtotal" >Grand Total: </label></div>
       </div>

      </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to get the input values of `Taxrow[i]` id . I tired `onchange` and `var price = document.TaxCalculator.price[i].value;` I know, I made something wrong.
and also I used `document.getElementById(node.value).value` using `onchange(getValue.this)`
 help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the functions `Total` and `Subtotal` have a parameter : `Total(i)` . Then generate the html to call the functions like this :

```
div.innerHTML =
                    '<div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="product'+i+'" id="product'+i+'" placeholder="Product Name"></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="price'+i+'"  id="price'+i+'" placeholder="Item Price"></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="qty'+i+'" id="qty'+i+'" onchange="subTotal('+ i +');" placeholder="Item Quantity"></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" id="tax'+i+'" onkeyup="Total('+ i +');" placeholder="Tax Percentage"></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input name="subtotal'+i+'" type="text" id="subtotal'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input name="salestax'+i+'" type="text" id="salestax'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
                    <div class="rTableCell"><input name="gtotal'+i+'" type="text" id="gtotal'+i+'" size="10" disabled></div>\
                        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(this)">';
```